# URL Redirection by removing a string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect some url .

for example if the url is

```
www.example.com/shop   valid

www.example.com/shop/red-product  need redirection to www.example.com/red-product

www.example.com/shop/green  need redirection to www.example.com/green

www.example.com/shop/any-string  need redirection to www.example.com/any-string
```

How i can do this . Please help .

My current htacess file is

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

Redirect 301 /bio/ https://www.example.com/bio/

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: no , it's a url

Comment: Does `www.example.com/green` load correct content for you?

Comment: yes . it will load correct content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace your code with this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^shop/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below rule should work we are matching the group after shop only.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/%1 [R]
```

Comment: Do you have any other rule working if please show them, I should've asked you before.

Comment: Oh man don't tell me this is related to wordpress if it is please use wp-rewrite module instead directly using htaccess.

Comment: i can't use the wp-rewrite rule because of some reason . but what we need is solution by using htacess